# typical way of running clojure programs

Tags: clojure

I'm new to Clojure and really confused about how I should run Clojure programs.

My first question is whether every Clojure program is a Leiningen package? If I want to write do I start by creating a new Leiningen project? Is there a to run Clojure programs similar to Python(ie `python pyfile.py`)

I realize this might be a stupid question, but I've been confused about this for a while and the few books/tutorials I've gone through don't seem to answer this question properly. Upto now, I've been running Clojure code just in the REPL.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Since you found leiningen straight off you're on the right track. It's not a silly question because answering it will help others get better google results.

- each clojure program should be a separate leiningen project, so you run `lein new project-name` for each of them.
- the result of building a Clojure project is the same as a Java project, a JAR file that gets run with `java -jar myproject-standalone.jar` for instance
- leiningen can build a wrapper shell script for you that produces a .sh file that just calls java -jar
- When I run clojure programs in production at work we just check them out of git and then  call `lein run` in the directory (actually Jenkins does this).

Comment: How do you suppress version number in the `.jar` target file?

Comment: add ` :uberjar-name "sample-standalone.jar"` to your project.clj file. see the sample project: https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/sample.project.clj#L382

Answer (score 9):

One thing to add to Arthur Ulfeldt's excellent answer is that lein creates a project.clj for you, and your main function (function where execution of the program starts from) can be defined in there. By default Leiningen creates the main function in a file called `core.clj` For example:

```
(defproject music "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "A workspace for my music experiments"
  :dependencies [
    [org.clojure/clojure "1.3.0"]
    [org.clojure/math.combinatorics "0.0.1"]
  ]
  :main music.core)
```

now my project can be run using:

```
lein run
```

and the main function in music.core will be run.

Answer (score 8):

To answer part of the question: "Is there a to run Clojure programs similar to Python?"
You really can just run a clojure script like this (called `hello.clj`):

```
(println "Hello!")
```

like this:

```
clojure hello.clj
```

EDIT: The following should work on *all* systems:

```
java -jar <path-to-clojure-jar>/clojure.jar hello.clj
```

On my system, the clojure.jar file is found in /usr/share/clojure/clojure.jar . The linux command to fire off clojure simply runs a command like the one above under the covers.

Comment: Does this work on all systems? I know that installing from aptitude on Ubuntu gives you a `clojure` command, but I don't know that this is true for other installs. Would be good to verify and update here.

Answer (score 6):

Probably the easiest way would be to use `lein-exec` to run Clojure scripts:

http://charsequence.blogspot.in/2012/04/scripting-clojure-with-leiningen-2.html

Comment: This really adds to the answers in this question, as part of the question is "Is there a way to run Clojure programs similar to Python?" This answer shows us how. Sometimes, I just want to run a script.

Answer (score 2):

my bash clojure script:

```
#!/bin/sh

export CLOJURE_EXT=$HOME/.clojure
export CLOJURE_OPTS="-Xmx1g -server"

LIBS=$(ls -1 $CLOJURE_EXT/* 2> /dev/null)
export CLASSPATH=.:$CLOJURE_EXT:$CLASSPATH:"$(echo "$LIBS" | tr \\n :)"

JAVA=${CLOJURE_JAVA:-java}
OPTS=${CLOJURE_OPTS:-}
MAIN=${CLOJURE_MAIN:-clojure.main}

breakchars="(){}[],^%$#@\"\";:''|\\"

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    exec rlwrap --remember -c -b $breakchars \
        -f $HOME/.clj_completions \
        --history-filename=$HOME/.clj_history --histsize=1000000 \
        $JAVA $OPTS $MAIN -i $HOME/.clojure.clj --repl
else
    exec $JAVA $OPTS $MAIN "$@"
fi
```

save them to $HOME/bin/clojure, chmod +x $HOME/bin/clojure,
copy clojure.jar and the 3rd party library into $HOME/.clojure,
you can run `clojure your_program.clj` as python pyfile.py

Answer (score 1):

As an update, a simple way to deal with clojure programs is to use [leiningen](http://leiningen.org/)

If you want to run small clojure scripts, use [lein-exec](https://github.com/kumarshantanu/lein-exec)

Answer (score 0):

Create an alias in your `.bashrc` file, or equivalent:

`alias clojure="java -jar path/to/clojure-x.x.x.jar"`

Then you can run `clojure my-file.clj` in your terminal.